# react native listen to touch event outside component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, listener, react-native-gesture-handler

I am creating a list of swipeable view components. I want to achieve that when one swipeable is active, touched anywhere else besides this swipeable view will close the swipe. Kind of like a textInput onblur.

I think adding a listener might help here, but not exactly sure how to achieve it.

I also have a stack navigator later that will push a page on top of the list. What I am looking for is the same, once outside the view, then close the swipe.

The code is like this, to be clear.

```js
<SafeAreaView>
  <ScrollView>
  {items.map(item => <CustomItem itemdata={item} />)}
  </ScrollView>
</SafeAreaView>
```

With custom item component like:

```js
import Swipeable from 'react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable';

....//React component stuff

render() {
  return (
  <Swipeable
    friction={2}
    overshootRight={false}
    renderRightActions={this.renderRight}
  >
    <View> 
    .....
    </View>
  </Swipeable>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next to your component, add `TouchableOpacity` that takes rest of display screen

---

```
render() {
 return (
      <>
       <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 1, height: "100%", width:"100%"}} onPress={()=>yourOutsdieClickAction()} />
       <Swipeable
          friction={2}
          overshootRight={false}
          renderRightActions={this.renderRight}
        >
        <View> 
        .....
        </View>
       </Swipeable>
      </>
      );
  }
```

Comment: Think I missed something here. If I put a touchableOpacity besides a Swipeable item, won't that block the touching for other Swipable items on the list?

Comment: you can play with this however fit, for example render it only when


`isActive && <TouchableOpac... />` or switch to `<TouchableWithoutFeedback/>`.
If you still face issues with this kind of approach, you can set it with `ref` and `onStartShouldSetResponder` as in https://www.jaygould.co.uk/2019-05-09-detecting-tap-outside-element-react-native/